# Binding to dependency property magic

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a dependency property:

```
public bool IsApproved //Dependency property
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsApprovedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsApprovedProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsApprovedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsApproved", typeof(bool), typeof(MyClass), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
```

And 2 controls binded to this property:

When I check/uncheck the checkbox the mypanel's visibility changes and its ok. 
But, when I put breakpoint into get and set of IsApproved - it's never stops there.

How does it work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Because the current WPF implementation of the XAML processor behavior
>   for property setting bypasses the wrappers entirely, you should not
>   put any additional logic into the set definitions of the wrapper for
>   your custom dependency property. If you put such logic in the set
>   definition, then the logic will not be executed when the property is
>   set in XAML rather than in code.

In other words, the framework does not utilize the CLR wrapper property. The `set` logic will of course be run if you directly set the CLR property through code. To detect framework changes to the property, you need to register a `PropertyChanged` callback using the metadata property during registration.

Answer (score 1):

The WPF databinding system modifies DependencyProperties directly through `SetValue()`, without going through your property setter (which doesn't actually need to exist).

To see changes, add a callback in the `UIPropertyMetadata`.